# A circuit that can clip a high voltage/ low current signal input to an Esp32?

Tags: zener, esp32, diode-clamp

I have a program for an Esp32 development board which detects the ignition spark from an engine and converts the frequency of the ignition to an engine RPM reading. The high voltage input peaks at about 75V but is less than about 20mA. It is an inducted current pulse from a coil of insulated wire wrapped 3 times around the spark plug lead (non-insulated) and connected to the following circuit (ignore the Arduino, its an Esp32 which accepts a signal with a maximum of 3.3V as an input):

[image]

It is a 1N4728 (3.3V) zener diode. This circuit reduces the voltage to the correct level, except for negative voltage spikes from the input signal, which shut down the Esp32 board until it is reset (see second photo). How can I improve this circuit to remove all the negative voltage spikes and keep the input in the safe 0-3.3V range?

[image: raw input from induction coil]

[image: same input but with 3.3V zener diode circuit]

Comment: Your Zener diode seems to be backwards. The way it is now, it will clip -3.3V and +0.7V. I assume you want that to be the other way around.

Comment: I've done something similar for my gokart. I added a 10nF capacitor to filter out some of the noise. Rather than measure frequency, I measured the period then software filter the result. Also be aware that the ignition coil can ring, I disabled further captures for a couple of milliseconds so that I didn't get stupid readings.

Comment: Yes, I probably have the Zener diode the wrong way around. I didn’t think so because my oscilloscope was showing (2nd photo) roughly positive 3V peaks with occasional negative voltage spikes.

Comment: Thanks for the capacitor tip Kartman!

Comment: @user253751 I reversed the direction of the Zener diode today. At low revs the voltage range is now +3V to -0.5V at low revs. A higher revs the negative voltage range increases to -1.5V and resets the Esp32. Would a normal diode (In the normal orientation) after the Zener Diode remove these unwanted negative voltages?

Comment: You could try using a separate normal or Schottky diode to clip the negative pulses. Maybe the Zener diode doesn't conduct so well in the forward direction since it's designed to be usde in reverse.